# JSESSION is being added automatically

Tags: java, websphere, jsessionid

In my websphere console session properties, the url rewrite is not enabled and I am 100% sure that I dont have any JSESSION suffix or anything on my jsp pages to generate and append the JSESSION. But the issue is on some specific pages like everything which its URI is xxRead.do. The JSESSION is appended at the end of URI automatically and I am not able to prevent it from happening.

Can anyone help me out here, thanks,

Comment: Per my understanding the server should fall back to writing the jSessionID in the URL only if cookies are disabled. Is that the case here?

Comment: Can you check what is the path of JSESSIONID cookie set in the browser ? (For the pages it does not append jsessionid)

Comment: @Thihara cookie is enabled of course!

Comment: @Santosh mate Ive got no path for jsessionid cookie neither for those pages that does not append nor for those that does! is it related?

Comment: @ComeRun, Cookies always have a [path attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path). There is one _possibility_ wherein the JSESSIONID is not set with root path (`/`). The rule is that the cookie set with a given path will not be available to pages whose path is outside the path of the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

JSESSIONID is what is used to keep track of a users HTTP session.

It's absolutely necessary for any web application that will maintain a user session.

As far as I know URL rewriting will only be used by any reasonable web server only as a fallback if cookies are disabled.

Please make sure that's not the case.

Comment: I am not using URL rewriting and I am storing the jsession in the cookie